# QML SwipeView has a opaque background. How can I make it transparent?

Tags: qt, colors, background, qml, transparency

In **QML** I have implemented a simple application with a `SwipeView` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    Rectangle{
        id: bg
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: tabBar.top
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

       Page{
        // Empty
       }

        Page{
            Rectangle{
                anchors.fill: parent
                color:"purple"
            }
        }
    }

    TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        width: parent.width;
        height: 30;
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Empty")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Purple")
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `SwipeView` the **red** background `Rectangle` shows, but as long as the `SwipeView` is present it is either **white** or **purple** depending on the page that is shown.

**With purple page selected:**

[image: With purple page selected]

**With empty page selected:**

[image: With empty page selected]

**With swipeview and tabbar commented out:**

[image: With swipeview and tabbar commented out]

So, *how can I make the red background shine through* (i.e. make the `SwipeView` transparent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SwipeView` by default is transparent. `Page` is not actually "empty". Because it inherits `Control`, it has a background property. By default, Page has a Rectangle set as a background. That is why you see white for the empty tab. [Page.qml Sourcecode](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/dev/src/imports/controls/Page.qml)

So you can do this:

```
   Page { background: null }
```

or:

```
    Page {
        background: Rectangle{                
            color:"transparent"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I figured this out myself only minutes after posting the Q. Thanks for being gentle with me!

Comment: As a note, I thought Page was mandatory, but you can use Item in its place if you like. This might save someone else.